# Why concatenation with ternary operator in Javascript is not working when given as String = String + typeof(result);

Tags: javascript

I cant understand the operator precedence while executing the expression that adds a string with the result of a ternary operator that checks a typeof value

```
var testobj = {
arg1 : "something",
arg2 : "",
msg  : function(m){      
       this.arg2 = this.arg1 + typeof m === "string"?m:"nothing";
       alert(typeof m);
       }
};

function testrun(){
    testobj.msg("hello");
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = testobj.arg2;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has higher precendence as compared to the ternary opeartor. Please see [operator precendence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

You need to precede the ternary operator to the concatenation. Without anything, it is being interpreted as:

```
('something' + typeof 'hrllo') === "string" ? m : "nothing"
```

which will be:

```
'somethingstring' === 'string' ? m : 'nothing'
```

Clearly, the result will be `nothing`. To correct this, change the expression to:

```
'something' + (typeof 'hrllo' === "string" ? m : "nothing")
```